# Integrating WEKA in web app (Django)

Tags: django, weka

I'm interested in adding results from a software suite WEKA (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weka_%28machine_learning%29) to a web app built in DJANGO. I'm not sure if it's possible but WEKA included a developers FAQ (http://weka.wikispaces.com/Frequently+Asked+Questions#x-Developing%20with%20WEKA). Anything in there that's useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weka is a Java-based application. This means you can use it with Django if you use [Django Jython](http://code.google.com/p/django-jython/). This may be the path of least resistance if you already have some code written that utilizes Weka.

Alternatively, I would suggest looking into [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) if you want a "normal" Python based machine learning library.

There are also a few other ways to integrate results from Weka into a Django application.  One involves wrapping your Weka code using some sort of external interface.  You could use JSON+HTTP, ZeroMQ, or a few other options.

Comment: Scikit-learn seems useful. The Jython direction seems a bit more work since all the data is generating using Python.